# How to get the arithmetic mean of various dates of MySQL from monday to sunday

Tags: php, mysql

I need to do a graphic of the arithmetic mean (I don't know if this is the correct word, sorry) between to dates and get the mean of hours for monday, tuesday... sunday. The hours per day of the week.

The table has the column `log_date` and I have an start day and end day and actually I do:

```
SELECT id, log_hours FROM log WHERE log_date >= DATE('2011-01-01') AND log_date <= DATE('2011-10-31')
```

This will give me the id's between this two dates. But I don't need this. What I need is a medium for monday, tuesday, etc. each day of the week to know what's the normal hours done everyday of it.

How I can do it? I'm also coding in PHP

**UPDATE:**

What I finally need:

```
MONDAY: 3, 4, 10, 12, 5, final result => 6,8
TUESDAY: 2, 8, 8, 2, 1, final result => 4,2
WENDSDAY: 1, 1, 10, 5, 2, final result => 3,8
THURDAY 8, 10, 12, 5, 6, final result => 6,2
FRIDAY: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, final result => 1
SATURDAY: 0, 8, 2, 0, 1, final result => 2,2
SUNDAY: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, final result => 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add an example with some data and the desired result?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021947/how-can-i-make-an-average-of-dates-in-mysql ?

Comment: Are you averaging the ids or a different column in the table?

Comment: @chawkinsuf no, it's the same table

Comment: @udexter The only columns you have specified in the table are id and log_date, but I assume you are not averaging the id. I made up a column called hours in my response.

Comment: @chawkinsuf sorry you're true. I've a value log_hours (FLOAT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DAYOFWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function to select values from a certain day. This query will give you the average of log_hours from each day in a single query:

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(log_date), AVG(log_hours) FROM log 
WHERE log_date >= DATE('2011-01-01') AND log_date <= DATE('2011-10-31')
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(log_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select AVG(columnToAverage)
     , DAYOFWEEK(log_date)
  from log
 where log_date between '2011-01-01' AND '2011-10-31'
 group
    by DAYOFWEEK(log_date)
```