# Calculate the average difference between two date columns for multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

I want to calculate the average difference between multiple dates: sent_date & view_date.

My table structure look like:

```
CREATE TABLE `mails` (
  `m_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sent_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `view_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`l_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

**Example data:**

sent_date: 2013-06-01
view_date: 2013-06-02
difference: 2 days

sent_date: 2013-06-01
view_date: 2013-06-05
difference: 4 days

Average: 3 days

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: I tried some things with DATEDIFF and SUM, but without any results

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021947/how-can-i-make-an-average-of-dates-in-mysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [DATEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) and [AVG()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)

```
select avg(datediff(view_date, sent_date))
from mails
```