# How do I query average time difference with multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, time, average

I have the following table that is basically a log of scans.

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| location_id   | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| code          | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created       | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_modified | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here is a simple example of some sample data.  Location_id of 1 is the enterence and location_id of 2 is the exit.  I want to know the average time it takes for a person (a code) to go from the entrance to the exit.

```
+----+-------------+------+---------------------+---------------+
| id | location_id | code | created             | last_modified |
+----+-------------+------+---------------------+---------------+
| 1  | 1           | 0005 | 2014-10-03 10:01:56 | NULL          |
| 2  | 1           | 0006 | 2014-10-03 10:03:08 | NULL          |
| 3  | 2           | 0005 | 2014-10-03 10:10:16 | NULL          |
| 4  | 2           | 0006 | 2014-10-03 10:10:18 | NULL          |
+----+-------------+------+---------------------+---------------+
```

I'm not exactly sure what kind of join I need to do for this query.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are the codes unique or will they be reused for another enter/exit?

Comment: Most codes will only be used once for each location, but some codes can go through each location multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a correlated subquery.  For each row with a "1", you need the next row for the same "code" and a "2":

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.created
        from table t2
        where t2.code = t.code and
              t2.id > t.id and
              t2.location_id = 2 and
        order by t2.id desc
        limit 1
       ) as exitdte
from table t;
```

You can then use something like `timestampdiff()` to get the difference in times and `avg()` to get the appropriate average.

For performance reasons, you should have an index on `table(code, location, id, created)`.

Comment: +1 Because of `timestampdiff()`. Other answers with `AVG` on `DATETIME` [won't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021947/how-can-i-make-an-average-of-dates-in-mysql)...

Answer (score 0):

We can do self join on the same table to get list of entrance time and exit times for each code.
The difference between these two times can be taken as average.

Here is the SQL fiddle : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a4d4

```
select t1.code, avg( t1.created - t2.created) average
    from Table1 t1
    Join Table1 t2
        on t1.code = t2.code
        and t1.location_id = 2
        and t2.location_id =1
    group by t1.code
```

Comment: You should improve your answer and not just dump a few lines of code.

Comment: @slybloty, thanks for the feedback. updated it with comments and sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this : (warning, oldschool SQL :))

```
SELECT AVG(b.created - a.created) as average
  FROM (SELECT created FROM table WHERE location_id = (should be a parameter) AND code = '0005') AS a,
       (SELECT created FROM table WHERE location_id = (should be a parameter) AND code = '0006') AS b
```